# How safe is chatting in iGoogle?

Tags: security, chat, google-talk, https

How safe is chatting in iGoogle - Chat in office? I am chatting over HTTPS.

Comment: Did u mean , tracking of your chats in company's Web security gateway software ?

Comment: yes, can company track my chatting?

Answer (score 5):

Safe from who - your boss?  On what - a company computer?  If the answers are 'yes' and 'yes', you can get a feel for your security situation in this way: go to a concurrent-use bathroom, sit in one of the stalls, and think about how much privacy you have.  The other users will probably not peer under the door, or over it, but you will also probably not be giggling or speaking threateningly or otherwise drawing attention to yourself.

Comment: nice analogy, +1